# error function graph

Tags: pgfplots, plot, pgfmath

Is there a simple way to plot the error function in latex?

Something like the graph shown in the wikipedia page would be great. The function doesn't seem to exist in pgfmath. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Thanks!

Comment: @percusse. Yessir. This is embarrasing. I did find that answer but only looked at the first posted solution which didn't plot anything. The solutions below solve this question using several alternatives.